# Pi is locked up. Do I need to reload Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian-jessie, boot-issues

The Pi that my students have been using to collect temp and light data has locked up.  When we attempt boot up, it gets stuck at this point in the process (see the image). I'm guessing we need to reload Raspbian-jessie.  Is that our only option?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=panic+unknown+block

Answer (score 1):

The SD card (or at least the device you boot from) appears to be corrupt.

I suppose there is an outside chance that a file system repair might help (a very slim chance I would guess).

You would need to mount the SD card in another Linux box to attempt such a repair.  You would also need to mount the SD card in another Linux box if you wanted to attempt to recover some data from the SD card.

The most reliable solution is to start again from scratch and re-image the card.  Of course this assumes the SD card itself is not faulty.